# How do I receive my first bitcoin?

Tags: receiving

My first experiences with bitcoin: I downloaded Multibit and then went to the CoinbitGet website. I copied and pasted my address at the site as they instructed and after verifying that it was the correct address, I did some tasks where I earned 240 ubtc. I did all that yesterday. Then this morning on the Coinbitget site it said I was paid - but nothing was shown on multibit. So the Multibit help said I should "reset blockchain and transactions" so I did that and let it run for about 13 hours. But still nothing. (I know Multibit is connected to the internet because it always shows the current bitcoin to dollar price in the upper right - even though it always says "connecting" rather than "connected" In the lower left). So I checked at http://blockexplorer.com/. and it says - "(2014-03-28 04:27:08) Received transactions: 1 Received BTC: 0.00024" - which was 16 hours ago but I still see nothing in Multibit. I read that Multibit is fast since it doesn't keep the blockchain on the disk. So what might I be missing? It is not a lot of money so I am not worried but would like to learn and am not sure what to do now. The address was correct. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your firewall is blocking the BTC node connections without blocking the price data. The price data is probably obtained through a normal port like HTTP or something, whereas the usual port for BTC connections is 8333. Other than that, the only other possibility that comes to mind is that it could have not got enough confirmations yet, blockchain.info can tell you how many confirmations your transactions have. Change the address in this URL to your own and see if the latest (top) transaction has 6 confirmations: https://blockchain.info/address/1DFNwqgF1HToPaveeoGZL4qdBDEZYUmC89.

Comment: Nitpicking: HTTP is not a port, it is a protocol that usually runs on port 80.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. I tried disconnecting my firewall for a few minutes earlier but the word "connecting" never changed to "connected" during that brief time (I was afraid to leave the firewall disconnected for more than a few minutes though, for security reasons). After reading your post I went to the URL you suggested and changed it to my address and it said I had 37 confirmations. But still nothing in multibit.

Comment: Jori, yes, I know. :)

Skimmel, I'm assuming you're using Windows. I'm not on Windows right now and I'm not sure when I will be, so I'm limited in how specific I can be. When my Peercoin wallet was being blocked by a firewall, it was by Windows' builtin firewall. Type "firewall" in the search box on the start menu. There are a number of tabs on the left, pick one of the bottom few. It will show a lot of programs with red Os (blocked) or green symbols (allowed). If you click at the top of the column of names, it will sort by allowed/blocked. Check to see if multibit is listed as blocked.